# Platform Cache always returns null

Tags: cache

I have setup Platform Cache on several dev orgs and each time I try to access a value I am getting null.  I followed the steps from https://trailhead.salesforce.com/modules/platform_cache/units/platform_cache_use.

1)Setup the cache trial
2)Setup a New Platform Cache Partition called CurrencyCache

When I run the code provided on for org cache and session cached, the cachedRate is always null.  Any idea why?  I have tried this on three different orgs with the same result.

```
// Get partition
Cache.OrgPartition orgPart = Cache.Org.getPartition('local.CurrencyCache');

// Add cache value to the partition. Usually, the value is obtained from a 
// callout, but hardcoding it in this example for simplicity.
orgPart.put('DollarToEuroRate', '0.91');

// Retrieve cache value from the partition
String cachedRate = (String)orgPart.get('DollarToEuroRate');
system.debug(cachedRate);

// Get partition
Cache.SessionPartition sessionPart = Cache.Session.getPartition('local.CurrencyCache');

// Add cache value to the partition
sessionPart.put('FavoriteCurrency', 'JPY');

// Retrieve cache value from the partition
String cachedRate = (String)sessionPart.get('FavoriteCurrency');
system.debug(cachedRate);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had to set Session and Org Cache allocation.  Once I did, the code above worked.

[image: Result]

Comment: Great job! Mark your answer as accepted (you may have to wait a day) so others having the same problem can benefit f rom your experience

Comment: Its was really helpful for me ...

Comment: Could you please right down the step, how to perform the above steps?